# Pass nls date format to SQL Loader control file

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Is this possible to pass NLS date forma to the SQL Loader control file? With query or through Linux/unix scripting. Is there a way to pass the value to the control file table column w/out hardcoding it please? 
Oracle version is 11.2.

```
SELECT value 
  FROM v$nls_parameters
WHERE parameter IN ('NLS_DATE_FORMAT', 'NLS_TIME_FORMAT')
/
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why would that be useful? The control file needs to match the format used in the data file, not in the database. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: Hi Alex. Different databases may have different NLS settings. We have multiple databases. Just curious if there is a way. I read that in version 12 there is DATE FORMAT option. Is there smth lk this in version 11? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but again, the format in the control file has to match the data file. The data will be inserted into the database as a proper date datatype, the NLS settings aren't relevanr.

Comment: Well, this is what I have been told to do - to match the date format to the NLS...

Comment: How will these NLS details be used?

Comment: @ William Robertson - I have bunch of data files that may or may not have dates in them. We get these files from some other company. In Oracle 12 there is default datetime format that can be set once in control file. I wonder is there smth lk this in Oracle 11.2. Thank you.

Comment: @Art - [do you mean this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-5740B2F9-C5C3-4D44-BB3F-81484417F02D)? That is [new in 12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-F4EE2A42-3986-4597-9088-A506173ABABF.htm#GUID-0FC02CF3-D149-4EA9-AE3E-CB869921CF40__BABEIEIC), so you can't do that in 11gR2, no. That still doesn't have anything to do with the DB's NLS settings though, it's the format expected in the data files.

Comment: Alex Poole - If there is a way to pass NLS date format to all dates in control file then I'd prefer this. If not then maybe this - see default datetime format:  https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/sql-loader-enhancements-12cr1
This probably should be closed. Thank you.

Comment: @Art - well, you could generate the control file with column-level date format argument (rather than the table-level introduced in 12cR1, in the link you provided and the two in my previous comment), and use the NLS parameters for that generation; which you coudl do with a query in a shell script. But the date format in the control file *has to match the format in the data file you are given*, and **not** the (default) date format in the database. I don't know how else to say that.

Comment: Alex, please copy this to answers.